# Accessing a module from all external JS files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, express

## Context

If I have say 2 classes e.g. **User.js** class and **Log.js** class which both access a database in their own unique methods, and I have installed a MySQL database module e.g. [db-mysql](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/).

## Question

How can I make it so the same (one) database instance can be used across both JS files?

## Thoughts

The two methods I can think of at the moment are not very memory conscious I guess:

1. pass db parameter in

   ```
   function(db){
       this.db = db;
   }
   ```
2. create an instance of it inside every class

   ```
   function(){
       this.db = require(moduleName);
   }
   ```

I’m just looking for the best way and need a bit of guidance.

Comment: go with "passing db parameter in" - I think it's the cleanest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate file where you connect to db. You keep that connection in that modules' closure, and when you later require that module, from any other file, it will use that same connection.

The simple example is something like this: lib/db.js

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql');
var settings = {  // import these from ENV is a good pattern
    hostname: 'localhost'
    , user: 'user'
    , pw: '****'
    , database: 'base'
}
var db =new mysql.Database(settings).on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
}).on('ready', function(server) {
    console.log('Connected to ' + server.hostname + ' (' + server.version + ')');
}).connect();

module.exports = db;
```

Then use this in other files:

```
var db = require('../lib/db');
db.query(...)
```

You can even abstract some basic queries in the db.js, something like:

```
function getUsers(filterString, callback) {
    db.query().select('id, username, email').from('users').where('username like', filterString)
    .execute(callback);
}
module.exports.getUsers = getUsers
```

Then in other files:

```
var db = require('lib/db');
db.getUsers('mike', function(err, rows, cols) {
         if(err) throw err;
         return [rows, cols];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the DB Parameter in.

Also create a new JS file called DBConfig.js where you can store the credentials for the MySQL DB. Use this javascript object to initiate your db. For Ex:

```
var db = require('DBConfig);
```

Inside your DBConfig.js, you can write

```
module.exports = {
 host:'<host_url>',
 username: root,
 password: '',
 database: '<database-name>'
}
```

In this manner you can use the same config accross the JS files.

Comment: thanks i will take a look into this approach as well and see what best suits my requirements :)